# C# ASP.NET MVC: Find out whether GET or POST was invoked on controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I find out whether a GET or a POST hit my ASP.NET MVC controller action?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can check `Request.HttpMethod` for that.

```
if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") {
    //the controller was hit with POST
}
else {
    //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can separate your controller methods:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ViewResult Operation()
{
   // insert here the GET logic
   return SomeView(...)
}


[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ViewResult Operation(SomeModel model)
{
   // insert here the POST logic
   return SomeView(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ActionResults For Get and Post methods separately  as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Operation()
{

   return View(...)
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Operation(SomeModel model)
{

   return View(...);
}
```