# Getting request type from ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, post, actionresult, controllercontext

I am extending the `ActionResult` class. In the `ExecuteResult` method I want to check if the action was a `GET` or a `POST` however there doesn't seem property in the `ControllerContext` class that will let me do that. Does anybody know how to check the request type from a `ControllerContext`?

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    //See if the request was POST
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.?)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }

    DoOtherStuff();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169490/c-sharp-asp-net-mvc-find-out-whether-get-or-post-was-invoked-on-controller-acti)?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe yes it is. The HttpMethod is buried in the ControllerContext class. Must have overlooked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y0

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    public HttpVerbs RequestHttpVerb(ControllerContext context)
    {
        return (HttpVerbs)Enum.Parse(typeof(HttpVerbs), context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, true);
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (this.RequestHttpVerb(context) == HttpVerbs.Post)
        {

        }
    }
```